# Can different subdomains of the same app prevent malicious attack like XSS?

Tags: security, xss, same-origin-policy

In my Rails app i have 2 subdomains,

one : **members.myapp.com** which is the area shared between **all members** (where they can login and manage their accounts)

Two : each member has its own website on a subdomain like this : **member1.myapp.com**, **member2.myapp.com**, **member3.myapp.com** etc...

Let's imagine that **user1.myapp.com** run a malicious js code in his site, can **members.myapp.com** be affected through XSS or other attacks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They would be able to set cookies that can be read by `members.myapp.com` - so if they are any coookie handling vulnerabilities on `members.myapp.com` then they could possibly exploit these. An example of cookie poisoning could be [session fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation).

XSS would not be possible unless both domains opted in. i.e. they would both have to contain the following code.

```js
document.domain = 'myapp.com';
```

Unless `members.myapp.com` is doing this, the [Origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) will not be shared between subdomains.

## Example of a cookie handling vulnerability

As mentioned, one type is [Session Fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation).

Now, say the attacker visits `members.myapp.com` and is given a random session cookie: `set-cookie: session_id=123456`.

The attacker then sends an email to an administrator saying there is a problem on his domain `user1.myapp.com`.

The attacker has some JavaScript code hosted on `user1.myapp.com`:

```js
document.cookie = "session_id=123456;domain=myapp.com";
```

The victim (an administrator of `myapp.com`) goes to the attacker's page and receives the cookie.

The admin later goes to `members.myapp.com` and the logs into their administrator level account. However, as the attacker has give the attacker their session ID (`123456`) in a cookie that can be read by `members.myapp.com` (as it was set at `myapp.com` level) the attacker is now logged in as the administrator. i.e. the attacker has managed to make the administrator share his session so when the administrator logs in, the attacker sharing his session is also logged in.

This is just one example of a cookie handling vulnerability. In this case the system should issue a new session cookie after login to prevent the session fixation attack.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I accepted your answer but I still don't understand well what do mean by " if they are any coookie handling vulnerabilities on members.myapp.com" ! I will be thankful if you can explain it more :) Thanks

Comment: @medBo: No problem. Example added.

Comment: @SliverlightFox thank you so much for the explanation, In ruby on rails, when I am logged in on memebers.myapp.com then I go to myapp.com I noticed that I am no more logged in because it can't read the cookie from members.myapp.com (they have different scope), also for the log-in I am using just "session" which is crypted by default in rails. is that not sufficient to protect me against that ?

Comment: also I found this post which seems similar to my situation (do you think the answer is correct): http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15734/is-my-current-method-of-handling-session-cookies-insecure

Comment: @medBo: I'm afraid not. It is the attacker that is setting the cookie at `.myapp.com` level. When the web server reads the cookie it cannot read the domain for the cookie so it will not know it is an attacker set cookie. In this instance you need to create a new session ID after login.

Comment: Humm interesting. even I am not sure I understand 100% but I think I've got some clarification and I will for sure go check some security course to understand more so I can protect my app.  just I am wondering how some known websites (which allow users to add custom html) do to protect their sites.