# How to secure a simple asp.net web application?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have a simple .net web application. My goal is that it starts with a log in page. When the registration is sucsessfull the user should get to the real content of the website. There are links which should be able to follow after registration but not before. I am workting on this for a few days and can´t find anything in the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Use the ASP.NET Membership Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Do not roll your own using `Session`. It will be [vulnerable to attacks such as session fixation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28875673/413180).

Although having said that, it does have some flaws, for example [it does not clear the server side of sessions after logout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20903746/413180).

This will enable you to use the [authorization rules in web.config](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config):

```
<location path="AdminFolder">
<system.web>

<authorization>
<allow roles="Admin"/> //Allows users in Admin role

<deny users="*"/> // deny everyone else
</authorization>

</system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

after registration successful redirect the page to real content and set the session to content page if user is not logged in redirect back to login or signup page

```
/*set session in  content page this will prevent the direct access to 
         content    page */ 
if(Session['success]==null){
redirect to login or signup page ;
}
```